# Reading FeatureLayer Attributes into 2D JavaScript Array in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, hosted-feature-layer

I am wondering if/how attributes of a Hosted Feature Layer can be read into a 2d Javascript Array using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.x?

I need a 2D Matrix of all attributes values to run some analysis.

Comment: what are `i` and `j` in your 2d matrix?, what type of geometry has the layer?

Comment: @cabesuon i would be the set of features and j attributes or a subset of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this example that I made might help you, it retrieves the features and build a matrix with them. You have to consider that this is restricted by the maximum of features per request configure in the service. If this is a problem, then you will have to make several request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Intro to FeatureLayer - 4.14</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      require([
        "dojo/on",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
      ], function(on, Map, MapView, FeatureLayer) {
        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "hybrid"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,

          extent: {
            // autocasts as new Extent()
            xmin: -9177811,
            ymin: 4247000,
            xmax: -9176791,
            ymax: 4247784,
            spatialReference: 102100
          }
        });

        /********************
         * Add feature layer
         ********************/

        // Carbon storage of trees in Warren Wilson College.
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
          url:
            "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0"
        });

        var featureMatrix; // [...attributes, esrigeojson]

        featureLayer.queryFeatures(featureLayer.createQuery()).then(fs => {
          console.log(`Number of rows: ${fs.features.length}`);
          featureMatrix = fs.features.map(g => 
            [...Object.values(g.attributes), g.geometry.toJSON()]
          );
          console.log('Matrix:');
          console.log(featureMatrix);
        });

        map.add(featureLayer);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```